# Where can I load certifcates from in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, ssl, certificate

My company has most of it's internal sites behind an SSO site (weblogin.comnpany.com using pubcookie). I'm trying to automate some tasks that need to log in with SSO to access some of these sites. Recently the weblogin page requires a client cert to be in order to even present the form to enter your password. So I need to load my client cert in order to get started with this automation.

I'd like to do something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886501/http-library-for-ruby-with-https-ssl-client-certificate-and-keep-alive-support

In this example, the client certs are loaded like this:

```
ssl_options = {
  cert: OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read('./certificate/client-2048.pem')),
  key:  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('./certificate/client-2048.key'), 'mypassword')
}
```

What are the equivalent file paths ('./certificate/client-2048.pem' and './certificate/client-2048.key') on Mac OS X?

I've read this over: [Where are digital certificates physically stored on a Mac OS X machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/992167/where-are-digital-certificates-physically-stored-on-a-mac-os-x-machine)

but I don't believe it mentions where private/public keys are actually stored.

Comment: Try `security list-keychains`. You can dump the content with the `dump-keychain` subcommand, too.

Comment: this just gives: `$ security list-keychains
    "/Users/myldap/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"`

Comment: @Ramy, that is correct. On macOS, personal certs and their matching private keys are stored in the keychain files and accessible via keychain APIs.

Comment: ok, maybe i'm still missing something: `$ dump-keychain /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
-bash: dump-keychain: command not found`